# Dropping every predictor once at a time in R

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

Let's say I have 4 predictors x1, x2, x3, x4. 
I want to have a code that drops every predictor one at a time.

For e.g.

```
set.seed(10)
y<-c(1:20)
x1<-c(1:20)*runif(20,min=0,max=2)
x2<-c(1:20)*runif(20,min=0,max=2)
x3<-c(1:20)*runif(20,min=0,max=2)
x4<-c(1:20)*runif(20,min=0,max=2)

lm1<- lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4) #full model 

#drop each predictor once 

lm2.1<- lm(y~x2+x3+x4)
lm2.2<- lm(y~x1+x3+x4)
lm2.3 <- lm(y ~ x1+x2+x4)
lm2.4 <- lm(y ~ x1+x2+x3)
```

etc.

Comment: Why do you want this? Chances are good that there are better statistical methods.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `drop1` if you want to see the contribution of each term:

```
drop1(lm1)

# Single term deletions
# 
# Model:
# y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
#        Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
# <none>              104.15 43.002
# x1      1    15.465 119.61 43.771
# x2      1    64.166 168.31 50.602
# x3      1    29.485 133.63 45.987
# x4      1     0.910 105.06 41.176
```

This is similar to `anova(lm1, lm2.1, lm2.2, lm2.3, lm2.4)`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and assume you're looking for finding the best model guided by the data.

To automate the process and find out which would be the best model (data wise):

```
step(lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4))
```

In your case it yields:

```
lm(y~x1+x2+x3)
```

as the best model.

This will also yield the contributions for each model. Note that it will consider in this case dropping each case, and evaluate which variable would be best to drop. Apparently `X4` would be best to drop in this case. It even checked dropping more variables, but in this case it did not yield a better model.

As pointed out, it does not make much sense usually to optimize a model based on data only. If you still insist, an advise would be to cross-validate and see if on new data the model still holds (which it shouldn't, based on this random data). Moreover, it never hurts to consider whether the model "makes sense" from a substantive point (and in fact is very much advised).

Comment: I woud add the disclaimer that stepwise regression has a bad reputation, and that it should be used with care.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess we at my study we make the clear distinction when we talk about "data driven" model selection.

Comment: And reviewing the choices the step-wise regression makes, does it make sense for my particular problem that a correlation is found (> rain, > groundwater).